# How to solve this Function problem with Java?

Tags: java, function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJwnX.jpg)Given an integer N, find all possible pairs of A, and B such that A + B = N and A and B both are natural numbers ??

My Code:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class UserMainCode
{

    public int AllPair(int input1){
          Int count0;
       int N =  Input1;

       if(N == A + B) {

       System.out.println(Allpair);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code samples as text, please don't post images of code.  Especially terrible sideways images take at a bad angle with your phone.

Comment: loop i N times where you add to arraylist a tupple of A and B where A = N - i and B = i

Answer (score 0):

**The basic algorithm to solve this problem:**

Used two for loop for "*a*" and "*b*" to find the pairs where *a + b == N*

```
public static Map<Integer,Integer> getPossibleSum(Integer n){
    Map<Integer,Integer> pair = new HashMap<>();
    for(int a = 0; a < n; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b <n; b++){
            if(a + b == n){
                pair.put(a,b);
            }
        }
    }
    return pair;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> pair = getPossibleSum(10);
    for (Integer key : pair.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("[a: %d; b: %d]", key, pair.get(key)));
    }
}
```

**OR**

You may only one for loop for "*a*", and the "*N - a*" will be the value of "*b*"

```
public static Map<Integer,Integer> getPossibleSum(Integer n){
    Map<Integer,Integer> pair = new HashMap<>();
    for(int a = 1; a < n; a++){
        pair.put(a,n-a);
    }
    return pair;
}
```

Comment: You could double the efficiency by avoiding duplicate pairs `for (int i=0; i<=N/2;i++) System.out.println(i+","+(N-i));`

Comment: yes, you are right. Since the pairs are repeating after N/2.